# Setting Authorization to specific parts of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, authorization

I have an events component, it displays a list of all the events in the database.

I am fairly new to authorization and react/redux in general 
and I can't figure out how to do the authorization properly.

I want everybody to see all the events all the time
as well as when you click on it you see the tickets available for that specific event(now it displays all tickets of all events, I'll have to fix that later)

but the main thing I want have happen now

is that either 
the 'CREATE EVENT' button is not displayed when a visitor isn't logged in
or that it is displayed, but when the visitor clicks on it 
and they aren't logged in
they are redirected to the /login page

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAllEvents, getEvent, addEvent } from "../../actions/events";
import { getUsers } from '../../actions/users'
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Moment from "moment";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class EventsList extends PureComponent {


  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getAllEvents();
  }

  getEvent(eventId) {
    this.props.getEvent(eventId);
  }

  addEvent = event => {
    this.props.addEvent(event);
  };

  render() {
    const { events, authenticated } = this.props;
    const eventsList = events.sort((a, b) =>{
     return a.id - b.id;
   });

    if (!authenticated) return <Redirect to="/login" />;


    return (
      <div>
        <Paper className="styles" elevation={4}>
          <h1>Coming Events</h1>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Event Name</th>
                <th>Starts</th>
                <th>Ends</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {eventsList.map(event => (
                <tr key={event.id}>
                  <td>
                    {" "}
                    <Link
                      className="link"
                      to={`/events/${event.id}`}
                      onClick={() => this.getEvent(event.id)}
                    >
                      {event.name}
                    </Link>
                  </td>

                                <td style={{border:"2px solid black"}}> {Moment(event.startDate).format('ll')}</td>

                                <td style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>  {Moment(event.endDate).format('ll')}</td>
                  <td />
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Link className="link" to={`/createEvent`}>
            CREATE EVENT
          </Link>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  console.log('users', state.users)
  return {
    events: state.events,
    event: state.event,
    authenticated: state.currentUser !== null,
    users: state.users === null ? null : state.users
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    getAllEvents,
    getEvent,
    addEvent,
    getUsers
  }
)(EventsList);
```

Any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Well, to hide the button you could just do smth like

```
{ if(this.props.authenticated) {
    <Link className="link" to={`/createEvent`}>
      CREATE EVENT
    </Link>
}}
```

To handle the redirect depending on which the user is authenticated or not you could use the onClick event of `Link` (I'm not sure the `Link` component exposes the onClick event, if not, just changed it to a regular button).

```
<Link className="link" onClick={this.onCreateEvent}> // maybe use a <button /> instead
  CREATE EVENT
</Link>

// ...

onCreateEvent() {
  if(this.props.authorized) this.props.history.push("/createEvent"); // this dependes on which version of React-Router you are using.
  else this.props.history.push("/login");
}
```